# NodeJs - Mongoose query in API failing in Mocha Chai test only

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js, chai

I am new to unit testing in Mocha/Chai and stuck on this issue. I have an POST for registering a new user. In that post, I check to see if the user is already in the database.

```
if(error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
console.log('check this ' +  req.body.email);
//console.log(`Connected to ${db}...`)
console.log(`Connected to ${User.db.mongoose}...`)
let user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email});
console.log(user);
if(user) return res.status(400).send('User already registered');
```

What I discovered the first test will register the user (inserting the information in the DB). What I found is that the second test fails.

```
it('Should reject duplicate new user', async() => {
        const res = await request(server)
            .post('/api/users/')
            .send({firstname: sFirstName, lastname: sLastName, email: sEmail, password: sPassword});

        expect(res.status).to.be.equal(400);
        expect(res.error).to.be.equal('User already registered');

    });
```

The reason for the failure is that the connection string that the Query fails, thus not returning any records. So, I tested the query in Postman and the POST API is working as expected. I am curious if anyone knows why the mongoose query will not work when I run the test in Mocha but work when I connect via postman. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

```
const {User, validate} = require('../models/user');


module.exports = function() {
    //Database connection 
    const db = config.get('db');
    mongoose.connect(db,{ useNewUrlParser: true })
        .then(() => console.log(`Connected to ${db}...`))
        .catch(err => console.error(`Could not connect to ${db}...`, err));
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone. I found the issue. I am using BeforeEach to clean up my user table, therefore the table is empty on the second test. I have altered my tests.

```
beforeEach(async() => {
    server = require('../index');
    await User.remove({});
});
```

Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

could you add a snippet of where you are connecting to the dB. Another thing you should check is if you set a different environment for your test like a test dB which you've not setup yet

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using a test env when I run the tests. I require index.js which calls several middleware functions, 1 being database.js

The part where I am puzzled is that the post works for the 1 test when call user.save and writes to my test database but User.findOne does not work.

Comment: Check if the test database is setup and the Mongodb Uri is correct for the test db

Comment: Mcdavid, the test is writing to the test database and storing information. The only issue is that the mongoose query is not working when running the test, it is however working on postmon.